# How Android is faster if it uses both JVM and Dalvik

Tags: java, android, jvm

I know that Android uses its own Virtual Machine called Dalvik, and it run .dex file instead of .class file.

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29),

> Programs are commonly written in Java and compiled to bytecode for the
>   Java virtual machine, which is then translated to Dalvik bytecode and
>   stored in .dex (Dalvik EXecutable)

Why Android needs to first compiled into bytecode for the JVM (.class) and then translates into Dalvik bytecode (.dex), why can't it directly compiled to Dalvik byte code from `.java` file ? ?

and If it uses two VM, first JVM and then Dalvik, then doesn't it make the compiling process slow ?

**Update**:

If i run a program in Java which will compile `.java` file into bytecode (`.class`) and then interpret it, and If i run the same program in Android, which will first compile `.java` file into `.class` and that `.class` into `.dex` and then run it...wouldn't Android be slower in comparison ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why Android needs to first compiled into bytecode for the JVM and then translates into Dalvik bytecode.? why can't it directly compiled to Dalvik byte code from .java file ?

It could, if you wanted to write a full compiler for that. The [new Jack compiler for Android](https://www.saikoa.com/blog/the_upcoming_jack_and_jill_compilers_in_android) apparently does this.

In general, it is easier to write a bytecode converter than it is to write a full compiler.

> then doesn't it make the compiling process slow ?

The conversion process does add overhead. "Slow" is a statement of opinion, and so I do not know whether the bytecode conversion makes the "compiling process slow" for your definition of "slow".

Comment: I mean if i run a program in Java which will compile `.java` file into bytecode and then interpret it. and If i run the same program in Android, which will first compile `.java` file into `.class` and that `.class` into `.dex` and then run it...wouldn't Android be slower in comparison ?

Comment: The OP may be overooking that the java bytecode to dex conversion happens once on the development machine as part of the overall process of turning java sources into an apk, rather than at runtime on the user's device.  There's normally no jvm or java bytecode on the device.

Comment: @Joe: "if i run a program in Java which will compile .java file into bytecode and then interpret it" -- that is not how Java works. "i run the same program in Android, which will first compile .java file into .class and that .class into .dex and then run it" -- that is not how Android works. As Mr. Stratton notes, compilation is a separate act from execution.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. One question, I just read through Jack and Jill Compiler that you have mentioned. Why Google didn't adopt it in the first place when it was writing Dalvik for android, I believe they were more than capable of writing their own compiler ?, and would compiler like `Jack` would ever replace what is the current process of generating `dex` file in Android ?

Comment: @Joe: "I believe they were more than capable of writing their own compiler ?" -- I am sure that they were *capable*. However, it is a lot of work, and they were busy with other things, I imagine. The only people who can answer that question would be engineers on the Android team at the time. "would compiler like Jack would ever replace what is the current process of generating dex file in Android" -- my understanding is that Jack takes `.java` code and generates `.dex` output directly.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks again Sir, Yes i saw the block diagram on their page about generating `.dex` from `.java`, my question was, will this process of generating `.dex` file directly from `.java` ever be adopted officially by Google ?, sorry if this question sounds lame.

Comment: @Joe: Considering that [it is already available for use](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill), it is already "officially adopted", at least by my definition of the term. In 2015, it seems probable that Jack and Jill will become the default toolchain, with an option to switch back to the existing `javac`-centric toolchain in case of compatibility problems. I have not tried Jack and Jill yet, and so I do not have first-hand experience in terms of compiler performance, compatibility, and such.

Answer (score 2):

The primary reason Android uses Dalvik is for app and system wide resources. The way Dalvik runs your app is by forking a process that already has most of the resources your app needs to run (not to mention this method makes sandboxing trivial).

There is a great (albeit old, since ART is the new kid on the block) article on why Dalvik is so useful in the context of mobile devices titled "[The Dalvik Virtual Machine Architecture](https://web.archive.org/web/20130202204701/http://davidehringer.com/software/android/The_Dalvik_Virtual_Machine.pdf)".

Comment: but why first generate a `.class` file ?

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question.  Also, it's not clear that the fork/copy-on-write idea could not have been retrofitted onto a more conventional sort of jvm - however Dalvik does have other differences such as being register-based which are significant on today's hardware.

Comment: What is the difference from the fork system call?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Why being register-based is important?